# How can we get a count of web error codes by site path for our magento 2.0 website?

Tags: magento

We have a magento 2.0 website, but we are struggling with some web performance and UX issues. A number of customers are reporting that they get 404 errors when visiting their cart, but it only seems to happen on some devices. We would like to be able to investigate which devices that these errors are showing up on. Is it possible to find different types of web responses (i.e. 502, 404, etc) along with the site path?

Thanks

We haven't tried anything yet, because we don't know where to look.